# Filter rows by one unique column of sorted values in Google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need an equation that filters by unique ID, using only the latest row (most recent row in time), and data found in that row.

I have data that is in the following format:

```
ID | Price | Area | Status | Date
10 | 20000 | 75   | Buy    | 20150301
11 | 30000 | 100  | Buy    | 20150201
10 | 23000 | 75   | Buy    | 20150101
23 |  4000 | 89   | Sold   | 20150601
11 | 34000 | 567  | Sold   | 20150120
```

After applying the filter equation I'd expect to see:

```
ID | Price | Area | Status | Date
23 |  4000 | 89   | Sold   | 20150601
10 | 20000 | 75   | Buy    | 20150301
11 | 34000 | 567  | Sold   | 20150120
```

**Attempt 1 (DID NOT WORK AT ALL)**

```
=FILTER(A2:E,A2:A<>OFFSET(A2:A,-1,))
```

From this suggestion: [Similar problem from back in 2012](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/XCvZ0MqsaY8) but I could not get this to work for me.

**Attempt 2 (MISSING ID 23 & WRONG DATES)**

```
=FILTER(A2:E6, A2:A6 = UNIQUE(A2:A6))
```

**Attempt 3 (MISSING ID 11, RIGHT DATES)**

```
=FILTER(SORT(A2:E6, E2:E6, FALSE), A2:A6 = UNIQUE(A2:A6))
```

[Example spreadsheet with above workings](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E4uzdLAHH2eoJCkkxb7C-vTBCXTq4Pob56Rt4eHgjjo/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this formula I entered in G2 of the sheet 'SHEETJP' in the spreadsheet you shared:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(query({row(A2:A),sort(A2:E)},"select max(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 label max(Col1)''",0),{row(A2:A),sort(A2:E)},{2,3,4,5,6},0))
```

Comment: Thanks @JPV +1 for demonstrating on the spreadsheet for me - most appreciated ;-)